# Why puddles instead of water flow?

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation

I was following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xIxUZpRk4Ac).
I created:

- circle as water source,
- pool,
- domain.

I selected **Cycles Render**;

*Objects have following settings:*
**water circle**: fluid type - Inflow, Volume - Shell, y = 1;
**pool**: fluid type - Obstacle, Volume - Shell;
**domain**: fluid type - Domain;
I pressed **Bake**, waited till it finish and got shaking puddles during play.
[image]

Here is my project: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pFP8xoK48LCwkeW36FYCCsEpdY7qOjPH

Comment: Also make sure the face of the circle is oriented so that it matches the axis of the inflow velocity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your screenshot it appears that your 'inflow' object is just a plain circle with no faces. This will result in only a very small inflow of fluid since it is the faces (shell) or the volume that contribute to the flow.

The simplest solution will be to select your circle inflow object, go into Edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>), select all (<kbd>A</kbd>) and press <kbd>F</kbd> to add a face. If you now bake your fluid simulation you should have a proper flow of fluid rather than just intermittent drips.

[image: fluid]

Comment: I had to set type=Inflow for circle, somehow it changed.

Answer (score 2):

Adjust the inflow velocity on your water circle. That controls the waterflow. Moving from 0 to 0.4 increased from dripping to flow.

Comment: I had to set type=Inflow for circle, somehow it changed. Thanks.